# Why test result of a transaction in mocha is wrong but it work correctly in REST test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, hyperledger-composer

I write a transaction in `hyperledger-fabric` and implement a test unit for it on the mocha. The transaction should set the title property of an asset.
After I update with `assetRegistry.updade` function, asset title value doesn't change but when I test in REST it works correctly.

CTO file

```
transaction TestOnChat {
  --> Chat chat
}

asset Chat identified by chatId {
  o String chatId
  o String title
  o DateTime createAt
  o ChatType type
  o Member[] memberList
  o Message[] messageList
}
```

permissions.asl

```
rule Test{
    description: "Member can expel other member chat"
    participant: "org.miluxas.chatnet2.User"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.miluxas.chatnet2.TestOnChat"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

logic.js

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {org.miluxas.chatnet2.TestOnChat} testOnChat - the teropooo
 * @transaction
 */
async function testOnChat(ex){

    ex.chat.title='fdfdfdf';
    const memberRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.miluxas.chatnet2.Chat');
    await memberRegistry.update(ex.chat);
}
```

test/logic.js

```
it('test chat', async () => {
    // Use the identity for Solivan.
    await useIdentity(solivanCardName);

    await createNewChat('32556','first solivan group chat','PUBLIC_GROUP');

    // Get the asset. and check if Ferzin added to chat
    const assetRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry('org.miluxas.chatnet2.Chat');
    const asset1 = await assetRegistry.get('32556');

    // Submit add other user to chat transaction
    const transaction33 = factory.newTransaction(namespace, 'TestOnChat');
    transaction33.chat = factory.newRelationship(namespace, 'Chat', '32556');
    await businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(transaction33);

    //console.log(asset1.type);
    asset1.title.should.equal('fdfdfdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake in `test/logic.js`. I had set `asset1` before submitting the `TestOnChat transaction` and checked it after the transaction is submitted.